# Using one script for multiple forms on a single page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, mobile, web-applications

I have built a multipage offline mobile webapp in a single html file. Each form requires a timestamp of when the form loads, since it won't be submitted to the server until the user has connectivity sometime later.
I'm using the following script to get the timestamp

```
<script>window.onload = function() {document.getElementById('date').value = Date();}</script>
```

I use this in each of the four forms:

```
                    <input name="date" id="date" type="text">
```

This works well for the first form that is viewed, but doesn't work for any of the other forms. I've tried everything that I can think of but I am a js novice. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id`s must be unique. If you must label multiple elements, use a `class` instead.

HTML:

```
<input name="date" class="date" type="text">
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var currentDate = Date(),
        dateElements = document.getElementsByClassName('date');
    for (var i = 0; i < dateElements.length; ++i) {
        dateElements[i].value = currentDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. I should have posted a week ago and saved myself a lot of time.